# Retrieve FB Information, Generate Image, Post to FB

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, html2canvas

Ok. Long title, sorry.

Made up a web page where:

1. Log to FB
2. Retrieve Name and Pic Profile
3. With this information, I generate a  with name and profile pic
4. With html2Canvas, I transform div into canvas

   5a. Trying to convert to PNG (Failed)

   5b. Post Canvas to FB (Failed)

So this is the point. I already set up from 1 to 4, and already done POST to fb. The problem is, Image generated with information can't handle profile pic.
When you ask to Graph Api (FB) to retrieve profile pic, it replies with a URL (Responde code 302) to originally pic.
So in my div I just add a img tag with src attribute of URL retrieved.

When I transorm div into canvas, it works. But when I try to transform Canvas in PNG (same as post to FB), profile pic disappear.
Reading Html2Canvas Documentation, it says problem occurs in picture not hosted in local server.

So. My question is not about any implementation, but about some line guide to achieve my result. I'm stuck and I have no idea what should I do.

Comment: please add the relevant code from your project, and EXACT error messages (maybe with a screenshot).

Comment: Your canvas is most likely “tainted,” and presumably there’s warning messages in that regard in the browser console as well. So go read up on what that means, and how it can be avoided.